# Image recognition with fixed position and limited image bank

Tags: opencv, real-time, image-recognition

I want to make a real time image recognition from my screen, with these constraints :

- I know where it is on the screen (like top center).
- For a specific position I know which image I can find.
- Full 2D.

For example, check which piece is in these specific squares on this specific online chessboard.

I never did it before, so I don't really know which tools I can use to do it.

I've heard about OpenCV, but I don't know if it's adapted to my constraints.

Comment: can you post some example pictures of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to make my own deck tracker, so I need to recognize which card is which, which hero is which...
https://imgur.com/GwE8cJq